# Is the HashingEncoder from Category encoders meant to be used over multiple variables at the time?

Tags: python, machine-learning, encoding, hash, categorical-data

I am trying to understand the output of the HashingEncoder when encoding more than 1 variable.

I am working with the credit approval dataset from the UCI, which can be found in [the UCI website](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/credit-screening/)

My understanding is that if I want to encode a variable with say 10 categories into 4 features, each category will be assigned a value from 0 to 3 through a hashing function, to then be assigned to one of the 4 features during the encoding. In other words, the hashing function returns the index that will allocate a 1 to the corresponding feature.

And I can see that in action if I run the following code:

```
from category_encoders.hashing import HashingEncoder

encoder = HashingEncoder(cols=["A7"], n_components=4)

encoder.fit(X_train)

X_train_enc = encoder.transform(X_train)
```

The encoded dataset contains the four "hashing features" at the beginning of the dataframe, and the number 1 indicates that the category was allocated to that particular feature:

```
     col_0  col_1  col_2  col_3 A1     A2     A3 A4 A5  A6      A8 A9 A10  \
596      0      0      1      0  a  46.08  3.000  u  g   c   2.375  t   t   
303      0      0      1      0  a  15.92  2.875  u  g   q   0.085  f   f   
204      0      0      1      0  b  36.33  2.125  y  p   w   0.085  t   t   
351      0      1      0      0  b  22.17  0.585  y  p  ff   0.000  f   f   
118      0      0      1      0  b  57.83  7.040  u  g   m  14.000  t   t   

     A11 A12 A13    A14   A15  
596    8   t   g  396.0  4159  
303    0   f   g  120.0     0  
204    1   f   g   50.0  1187  
351    0   f   g  100.0     0  
118    6   t   g  360.0  1332
```

And if I explore the unique values of those features, I can see that they only take values 0 or 1:

```
for c in ["col_0", "col_1",  "col_2", "col_3"]:
    print(X_train_enc[c].unique())

[0 1]
[0 1]
[1 0]
[0 1]
```

Now, if I instead encode multiple categorical variables using the HashingEncoder, I obtain something that I am not sure I understand:

```
from category_encoders.hashing import HashingEncoder

encoder = HashingEncoder(cols=["A5",'A7', "A12", "A14"], n_components=4)

encoder.fit(X_train)

X_train_enc = encoder.transform(X_train)
```

The encoded dataset contains the four "hashed features" at the beginning of the dataframe, but now they take values beyond 0 and 1:

```
     col_0  col_1  col_2  col_3 A1     A2     A3 A4  A6      A8 A9 A10  A11  \
596      0      2      2      0  a  46.08  3.000  u   c   2.375  t   t    8   
303      0      1      2      1  a  15.92  2.875  u   q   0.085  f   f    0   
204      1      0      2      1  b  36.33  2.125  y   w   0.085  t   t    1   
351      0      1      2      1  b  22.17  0.585  y  ff   0.000  f   f    0   
118      1      1      2      0  b  57.83  7.040  u   m  14.000  t   t    6   

    A13   A15  
596   g  4159  
303   g     0  
204   g  1187  
351   g     0  
118   g  1332
```

Which I corroborate  if I explore the unique values of those features:

```
for c in ["col_0", "col_1",  "col_2", "col_3"]:
    print(X_train_enc[c].unique())

[0 1 2]
[2 1 0 3]
[2 0 1 3 4]
[0 1 2]
```

Do I understand correctly that a number 2 would mean that categories from 2 different variables were allocated to that particular feature?

Is this the expected behaviour?

Somehow, I expected that I would get 4 hashed features per variable, and not 4 hashed features in total. Should this not be the case?

Comment: I see you also [asked at the github repo](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/category_encoders/issues/350), which is probably the better place since this seems to be a decision taken by the package.  But I will point out in the documentation that it's "a **multivariate** hashing implementation" (emphasis mine), so I think this is what they wanted.

Comment: Yep, reading the original articles in more detail, the method is meant to summarize a huge feature space in a smaller feature space (dimensionality reduction). It was mostly designed to work with large text corpuses in the form of bag of words or some sort of tokenization. So not sure how much it is useful for categorical variables. I guess it would make sense for those with high cardinality. Also, it produces encodings on the fly, so can handle unseen categories out-of-the-box. Thinking out loud.